# Having many JQuery Toggle buttons on the same page

Tags: jquery, toggle

I just realized another problem with my so called "solution" =)

My JS Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        function runEffect(){ 
            var selectedEffect = $('#slide').val();
            var options = {};
            if(selectedEffect == 'scale'){  options = {percent: 0}; }
            else if(selectedEffect == 'size'){ options = { to: {width: 200,height: 60} }; }
            $("#effect1, #effect2").toggle(selectedEffect,options,500);
        };
        $("#moduleMenuBtn1, #moduleMenuBtn2").click(function() {
            runEffect();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

I have 9 boxes, all with a "Menu" button that should slide down a menu for a particular box (not all at once).

How can I change the code to get "Menu" button1 to react with "menu1" and not all menus at once?

My solution to have #menuBtn1, #menuBtn2, etc, is not working =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of IDs (like your previous question) use classes, like this:

```
<div class="moduleMenuBtn">Menu</div>
<div class="effect">Some Content</div>
```

Then in your code you can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) to find the corresponding `.effect` relatively, like this:

```
$(function() {
    $(".moduleMenuBtn").click(function() {
        var selectedEffect = $('#slide').val();
        var options = {};
        if(selectedEffect == 'scale'){  options = {percent: 0}; }
        else if(selectedEffect == 'size'){ options = { to: {width: 200,height: 60} }; }
        $(this).parent().next(".effect").toggle(selectedEffect,options,500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

This makes it work for any number of `.moduleMenuBtn` and `.effect` pairs in the page.  To see other methods to find things relatively, check out [the tree traversal section of the API](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/).

Comment: Thanks!

But when I used your script it doesn't work anymore =) Could it be because they are not siblings, the ".moduleMenuBtn" and ".effect" div's are separated likes this:

<div class="moduleTopContainer">
<divclass="moduleMenuBtn">Menu</div>
</div>

<div class="effect" style="display: none;">
"Some Content"
</div>

Thanks!

Comment: @Erik - Try `.parent().next('.effect')` instead, any issues then?